# Lazarus Public REST Api usage

Tags: api, request, lazarus

I'd like to know how to implement Pubilc API in lazarus. I am familiar with Lazarus/Delphi since I made some apps on it like 20 years ago. Since then I have moved to iOS. In iOS we have NSURLSession to connect to server for any GET/POST request. I am wondering how to do the same in Lazarus.

Comment: Nvm found a way to do it with Synapse.

Comment: Note that FPC can use Ojbective C classes to some degree and even derive from them